# I can't redirect ionic page using tab forms

Tags: ionic-framework

I can't redirect a ionic 4 tab page to other tab page using parameters.

I'm using tabs-routing.module.ts with this code:

```
 {
    path: 'tab2/:id',
    outlet: 'tab3',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('../tab2/tab2.module').then(m => m.Tab2PageModule)
      }
    ]
  },
  /* {
    path: 'tab2/:id',
    outlet:'tab3',
    component: Tab2PageModule
  }, */
```

The view contains:

```
 ion-button size="small" href="/tabs/tab2/{{f}}/"...
```

or

```
 ion-button size="small" href="/tab2/{{f}}/" ...
```

The browser says:

> core.js:9110 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'tabs/tab2/1/'

When I use:

```
ion-button size="small" href="/tabs/(tab3:tab2/{{ f }})" ...
```

The url in browser is
http://localhost:8100/tabs/(tab3:tab2/2)

The content in the browser disappears and only shows the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

To navigate within your app you should use `routerLink` directive like the following:

```html
<ion-button size="small" [routerLink]="['/tabs/tab2/', id]">
```

[routerLink directive documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink)

It seems there is an other issue. Your declared routes are: `tab2/:id` and `tab2/:id`. Yet you're routing to `/tabs/tab2/1` while you should be routing to `/tab2/1`
Like this:

```html
<ion-button size="small" [routerLink]="['/tab2/', id]">
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, now it works correctly. However, now the controller does not get the parameter correctly. 

Please look my answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Happy to help! Do you mind voting for my answer? I'm Kind of tired to help to receive no vote. After that I will have a look at what's still not working

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, now it works correctly. However, now the controller does not get the parameter correctly.

In this screen I will call the details module
[main module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyVR1.png)

But the module that receives the parameters does not get the data sent

This is how the screen looks without parameters

[second module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wQSc.png)

When I add the complete code (using the parameter)

> ion-button size=small routerLink=/tabs/tab2/{{f}}
>
> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes.
>   URL Segment: 'tabs/tab2/3' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL
>   Segment: 'tabs/tab2/3'

The content of file tabs.routing.module.ts is

```html
{
        path: 'tab2/:id',
        outlet: 'tab3',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () =>
              import('../tab2/tab2.module').then(m => m.Tab2PageModule)
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab2/:id',
        outlet: 'tab3',
        component: Tab2PageModule
      },
```

the content of file tabs2.page.ts is

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ListadoPokemonService } from '../servicio/listado-pokemon.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab2',
  templateUrl: 'tab2.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab2.page.scss']
})
export class Tab2Page implements OnInit{
  idPokemon: string;
  nombrePokemon: string;
  listado:any;

  constructor(private activatedroute: ActivatedRoute, private servicio: ListadoPokemonService) { }

  ionViewVillEnter(){
    this.idPokemon = this.activatedroute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    // this.nombrePokemon = this.activatedroute.snapshot.paramMap.get('nombre');

    this.servicio.getData('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/'+this.idPokemon+'/').subscribe(data=>{
      console.log(data);
      this.listado=data;
    });       
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance for your help i'm php & visual studio developer but new in angular & ionic issues.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it, just add the following code

```html
{ 
        path: 'tab2/:id', 
        //component: Tab2PageModule 
        loadChildren: () =>
              import('../tab2/tab2.module').then(m => m.Tab2PageModule)
      },
```

in tabs-routing.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by placing the redirect object above the empty path. like this example:

```
    const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/user/profile-u',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: UserPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'job-applying',
        loadChildren: () => import('./job-applying/job-applying.module').then(m => m.JobApplyingPageModule)
      }, ...
```

I hope this helps you. I realize this seems like a trivial solution, but some things in this framework are just a little finicky.